# Yii2 Ajax Filter onblur

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I'm new to yii2 web development and it's the first time I work with javascript.
I've already made search results appear using JPax. I only need to start filtering results (inside Gridview) as soon as user removes cursor from either search field (name/price) of course without pressing the search button. I think it has to do with onblur. The problem is I don't have any idea where should I start. Do I have to write inline js code inside text fields?
Or create an asset? What should I do?

[image]

Comment: you should add some code

Comment: I only need to know what I should do (like steps). And code will only make the question bigger. Also there isn't anything in the original code that has to do with answer. Anyway if anyone needs to know something I'll post it down. Thanks @Sageth

Comment: I think my answer will be usefull for you, Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways.

**1-Create a asset**

You can create a asset with your own JS and CSS files

[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html) a great guide to use it

**2-Register only one JS**

[View](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html) Class have a really usefull method, `registerJsFile()` you can use it to load an specific JS to your view.

In `controller` you can use:

```
Yii::$app->view->registerJsFile('path/file.js', [
                                    'depends' => [
                                         'yii\web\YiiAsset',
                                         'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
                                    ]
                                ]);
```

Use `depends` option to load your js AFTER `Jquery`

Comment: I'll give it a try @Sageth